# Checkbox issue where clicking on Checkbox 3 marks Checkbox 1 and etc

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have never encountered a problem like this before.
When I click checkbox 1 it checks checkbox 1, but if I click on Checkbox 2 or 3 , they still check the first box.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox65" class="css-checkbox med" />
    <label for="checkbox65" class="css-label med elegant" name="avatar" value="image1"/></label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox65" class="css-checkbox med" />
    <label for="checkbox65" class="css-label med elegant" name="avatar" value="image2"/></label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox65" class="css-checkbox med"/>
    <label for="checkbox65" class="css-label med elegant"  name="avatar" value="image3"></label></td>
</tr>
```

I am using checkbox styles from csscheckbox.com - idk if that is the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: All your checkboxes have the same ID, they need to be different for each checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the Ids of input checkboxes and for values of labels.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox65" class="css-checkbox med" />
    <label for="checkbox65" class="css-label med elegant" name="avatar" value="image1"/></label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox66" class="css-checkbox med" />
    <label for="checkbox66" class="css-label med elegant" name="avatar" value="image2"/></label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox67" class="css-checkbox med"/>
    <label for="checkbox67" class="css-label med elegant"  name="avatar" value="image3"></label></td>
</tr>
```

This should fix.

Comment: Thank you , I had only used simple checkboxes before